# Check if specific object property is unique in the list

Tags: java, collections, stream

I have a list of objects where I need to check whether specific fields of the objects are unique.

```
public class SomeBean {

  private String name;
  private String value;

}

List<SomeBean> beans = ...
```

So I need to check if all `value` fields and all `name` fields are unique independently (all values are unique and all names are unique). 
The obvious solution is to get list of `List<String> names ...` and `List<String> values` and check for uniqueness separately but in my case this lists could be rather large. And as this list comes from the outside I could not change the initial data structure.

So what is **the most efficient** way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Fields are independently unique or the combination is unique?

Comment: Independently . Updated the question

Comment: In my opinion you'll have to use HashTable(s) to be able to check that. If you don't do that, you'll end up with O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

The most easier solution to remove duplicated items is to load your items to `Set` because Set is not allowed duplicated values. You can use `HashSet`.

**OR**

You can add your items to `HashMap<String, SomeBean>` wher you can use `getName() + getValue()` as a key:

```
HashMap<String, SomeBean> myMap= new HashMap<>();
myMap.put(someBean.getName() + someBean.getValue(), bean);
...
```

Comment: I disagree with _you need to override the equals() and hashCode() of your bean_ It's more simple than that.

Comment: I would not override `equals` and `hashCode` of the DTO only to be able to complete this task. But I guess I could create TreeSet with custom comparator.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible way is to use `TreeSet` collection. You should override `compareTo()` method to prevent duplicate items